# TcpClient maximum packet size for sending data

Tags: vb.net, tcpclient

I am building a communication library based on the Net.Sockets.TcpClient class. During some unit tests I wanted to test how large a datapacket could be before running into problems. My theory was that the actual size would not matter because the TcpClient would split the data into parts because of its internal sendbuffer. But the actual size did matter because somewhere around 600KB I discovered loss of data.

What my test does is create a local server and a local client that connect with each other. Then it sends a specific (large) package in a loop to test if the server receives it well. I left out all checks but after sending the data a check runs that the data is exactly the same as what was send before looping again. So there is never more data in the pipe than the size that I specified. This code is the client part in my unit test. The server part is a whole library so I cannot post that.

```
Using myClient As New Net.Sockets.TcpClient()
    myClient.BeginConnect("127.0.0.1", ServerPort, Nothing, Nothing)
    'Code that checks if the connection has been made
    
    'Create a large string
    Dim SendString as String = StrDup(1024000, "A")
    Dim SendBytes as Byte() = Text.Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(SendString)
    'Loop the test
    For i As Int32 = 1 To 10000
        Wait.Reset()
        myClient.Client.Send(SendBytes)
        Wait.WaitOne(10000)   'Wait for the server to acknowledge
        'Run checks to make sure the data is good, otherwise end loop
    Next
    
    myClient.Close()
End Using
```

What happens is that at some random point the server does not receive all data. It looks like sending 1.024.000 bytes of data works most of the times but not always. The iteration at which it fails is random but a loop will never finish 10.000 iterations successfully. I tested the loop with 512.000 bytes and that works. I also tested 600.000 bytes and that failed. I do not know what the actual size is at which it starts failing because it does not seem to be a hard limit. I cannot figure out the problem. Is the TcpClient somehow limited or do I exceed an internal buffer of some kind? I checked the SendBufferSize of the TcpClient and it was 65536. I have no idea if that has anything to do with it. Packages larger than that buffer seem to be sending just fine.

Comment: It's quite obvious that there's no such limit. Otherwise you wouldn't be reading StackOverflow and no .NET application would be able to use the network. You aren't sending packets, you're bypassing TcpClient sending buffers piecemeal through the underlying socket. Applications that need to send a lot of data use streams instead. There's no error handling or logging code, but there *is* some extremely suspicious blocking code, in an otherwise synchronous method. Are you sure the client or server side blocking didn't cause a timeout? Are there other threads that use `myClient`?

Comment: The remarks in [Socket.Send](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.net.sockets.socket.send?view=net-5.0#System_Net_Sockets_Socket_Send_System_Byte___) explain that `in nonblocking mode, Send may complete successfully even if it sends less than the number of bytes in the buffer. ... There is also no guarantee that the data you send will appear on the network immediately. To increase network efficiency, the underlying system may delay transmission until a significant amount of outgoing data is collected` TcpClient takes care of all that, but your code uses the Socket directly

Comment: Besides, your code uses `BeginConnect` but never waits for the operation to finish. This would result in errors in a real network. Use [ConnectAsync](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.net.sockets.tcpclient.connectasync?view=net-5.0) with `await` instead of the pre-.NET 4 `BeginConnect`: `await myClient.ConnectAsync("127.0.0.1", ServerPort);`

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos My code waits for the connection to finish but for the sake of a small example I left that part out. It's not part of the problem because the connection works fine. I will check if my test will run better when using the stream.

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos Using GetStream and Stream.Write has the same problem.

Comment: But you can still read and post to StackOverflow. Which is an ASP.NET Core site and uses TCP, because HTTP uses TCP. You posted only partial code, no errors or logs, no server code, nothing that can actually reproduce the error. It's impossible to say what's wrong with code that wasn't posted. You don't need the actual server to reproduce the problem (unless this is a *server* error). You can easily create a TcpListener that listens to your TcpClient. Can you reproduce the problem this way? If so, *post the code in the question*.